# Why do I get this error when I start a payment using react-native juspay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, payment

I am implementing juspay payment gateway in react-native in this code.
I am getting the following error:

> attempt to invoke the virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference in react
>   native

Here is the code it should open payment page, but it gives an error. Please help me.

```
import EcReactNativeLibrary from '@juspay/ec-react-native-library';

var nbPayload = {
                  opName: "nbTxn",
                  paymentMethodType: "NB",
                  paymentMethod: "enter bank code", // 
                  redirectAfterPayment: "true",
                  format: "json"
                }
//Here payload format is specified for netbanking transaction. For different types of payload types 
//for other operations, refer https://developer.juspay.in/docs/expresscheckout-sdk


var requestPayload = {
                baseParams: {
                  merchant_id: "my-merchant-id-test",
                  client_id: ""sgsjjvxbhwu15shq67161",
                  order_id: "272682162817218727",
                  amount: "1.00", //eg: "1.00"
                  customer_id : "pass customer id",
                  customer_email : "pintu0002@gmail.com",
                  customer_phone_number : "809254xxxx",
                  environment: "sandbox" 
                },
                serviceParams: {
                  service: "in.juspay.ec",
                  session_token: "pass client auth token",
                  endUrls: ['https://www.reload.in/recharge/'],
                  payload: nbPayload 
                },

              }
              EcReactNativeLibrary.startPayment( 
                  JSON.stringify(requestPayload), 
                  (successResponse) => {
                    console.log(successResponse);
                  },
                  (errorResponse) => {
                    console.log(errorResponse);
                  } 
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `requestPayload` is malformed. The `endUrls` should be an array of strings.

```
endUrls: ['https://www.reload.in/recharge/'],
```

The reason for the error is that since the object is malformed, it's not being properly assigned, so when the JSON serializer tries to convert it to a string, it fails.

Comment: endUrls: ['https://www.reload.in/recharge/'], using this way still getting this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference in react native